# If A is an $n\times n$ square matrix such that $A^3=A$ , then show that $\operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{tr}(A)$ is even

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

> If $A$ is an $n\times n$ square matrix such that $A^3=A$ , then show that $\operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{tr}(A)$ is even.

$\mathbf {My \ attempt}:$ Actually, I have been trying over this problem which was posed as a multiple choice question in an exam .
  First of all to show that  $\operatorname{rank}(A) ≥ \operatorname{tr}(A)$ .
  Consider, the rank factorization of $A$, $A= PQ$ where $P$ and $Q$ are $n\times r$ and $r \times n$ matrices respectively for $r=\operatorname{rank} (A$) , and as $P$ and $Q$ are left and right invertible, then $$\operatorname{tr}((QP)^2)=\operatorname{rank} A\geq \operatorname{tr}(QP)=\operatorname{tr}(PQ)=tr(A). $$
  But, I can't approach for the part stated in the question .
 Any help is appreciated .

Comment: Can someone please edit the text using Latex or MathJax (as I am completely unable of doing it) ???

Comment: It may be worth your while to check out https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $A^3=A$, the eigenvalues of $A$ are from $\{0,+1,-1\}$. 
In addition, the $A$ is diagonalizable, as the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $t^3-t=(t-1)(t+1)t$, hence it factors into linear factors.

Let me denote there algebraic multiplicities by $n_0,n_+,n_-$, respectively. 
Then the rank of $A$ is equal to 
$$
rank(A)=n_++n_-,
$$
while the trace is (the sum of the eigenvalues)
$$
tr(A) = n_+-n_-.
$$
So 
$$
rank(A) + tr(A) = n_++n_-+n_+-n_- = 2n_+,
$$
which is even.